# Generating REST Controller Interfaces and DTO Models from API First Approach in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, openapi, openapi-generator

**Question:**
I'm using the latest version of Intellij Ultimate IDE and I'm looking to develop a REST API based on Spring Boot. I'm open to using either Maven or Gradle as the build system. My intention is to follow an API-first approach, wherein I want to generate the REST controller interfaces and DTO models.

I've placed my own `api.yaml` file in `*/src/main/resources` and attempted to generate the code, but this process generates a multitude of files, including Gradle build files, etc. What I'm aiming for is to have only the controller interfaces and DTO models generated, and I want them to be placed in the directory `*/src/main/java/de/test/restapi/gen`. This folder would be situated hierarchically within the same project, alongside my existing codebase.

Furthermore, it's crucial that the generation process occurs before the actual compilation during the build process. Despite my efforts to find a solution online, I haven't been able to locate a suitable method. Could you please assist me with this? Thank you very much.

EDIT:
I bootstrapped a demo project to clarify my problem:
[GitHub](https://github.com/pboehm90/spring-openapi-template)

[image: I generate the files with the OpenAPI Generator 6]

[image: You see the unneccesary files. The generator is creating an whole project]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recommend you use a plugin for Maven and Gradle, called scs-multiapi-plugin. Have support for OpenAPI and AsyncAPI, and I think it's your ideal solution since you can choose what you want generate.

https://github.com/sngular/scs-multiapi-plugin

I was a developer from there for a few months, so I think that plugin could solve your problem

If not you can try OpenAPI generator too, you have a few solutions for your problem

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you have a broad experience in this point, would you like to try to investigate the problem in my example project? I´m using the openapi generator in version 6.

Comment: Well, i dont know how achieve the behavior you expect with the openapi generator, I suggest you if you want keep using it, check the docs from them, because the thing you want (Only have the API Interface and Model) its the expected behavior of the first plugin I put you.